# Bootstrap Modals keep adding padding-right to body after closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and Parse framework to build a small web app. But those Bootstrap modals keep adding padding-right to the body after closed. How to solve this?

I tried to put this code in my javascript:

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("element.style").css("padding-right","0");
});
```

But it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix this?

My code:

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Admin panel</button>

         <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">

                      <!-- header -->
                      <div class="modal-header"> 
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                      </div>

                      <!-- body -->
                      <div class="modal-body text-center" >
                          <input class='form-control' type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Username" ng-model='username'>
                          <input class='form-control' type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model='password'>
                        
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="loginButton" ng-click="goToAdminPanel()">Login</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeButton">Close</button>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                 </div>
                </div>
           </div>

        <div id="adminPanel" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">

                      <!-- header -->
                      <div class="modal-header"> 
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Admin Panel</h4>
                      </div>

                      <!-- body -->
                      <div class="modal-body" >
                        
                        </div>
                        
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="saveButton">Save</button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeButton">Close</button>

                      

                    </div>

                 </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

```
    $scope.goToAdminPanel = function(){
    Parse.User.logIn($scope.username,$scope.password,{
        success: function(user){
            $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
            $('#adminPanel').modal();
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert('Wrong username and/or password');
        }
    });
}
```

I am using bootstrap and Parse framework to build a small web app. But those Bootstrap modals keep adding padding-right to the body after closed. How to solve this?

Comment: Its not just add `padding-right` but also add class as  `modal-open` for `overflow: hidden` its just for hiding the *scroll-bar*.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Hi, I tried to override the `modal-open` with `padding-right:0 !important;` but it does not work, do you know why?

Comment: please check my answer below, it surely help you.

Comment: You almost got it. You're firing the `padding-right` css property update on the correct event, but you're firing it on the wrong element. It needs to be fired on the `body` element. Please check out my answer below.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65027287/7186739

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This might be a glitch from Bootstrap modal. From my tests, it seems like the problem is that `#adminPanel` is being initialized while `#loginModal` has not been totally closed yet. The workarounds can be removing the animation by removing the `fade` class on `#adminPanel` and `#loginModal` or set a timeout (~500ms) before calling `$('#adminPanel').modal();`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I removed the class `.fade` from `#loginModal` and it works.

Comment: What if I want to fix this, and maintain modal animation at the same time?

Comment: @LeonardoMontenegro I also wanted this and recently I also posted the same question the issue was animation was removed but I fixed it by first removing the fade class just before hiding and adding it again just after that hide it worked though it's a workaround not a proper solution unless bootstrap fixes it in there file itself

Answer (score 156):

I have just used the css fix below and it is working for me

```
body { padding-right: 0 !important }
```

Comment: You've got the correct css property, but this needs to be fired on the `hide.bs.modal` bootstrap event. Please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 70):

```
.modal-open {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Just changed to

```
.modal {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the real right answer - "don't use the fade feature" is a compromise, not a solution.

Comment: I did the same thing, but there might be a need to add "overflow: auto !important" as well because when the modal is shown, the scrollbar is also hidden.

Comment: I used the selector ".modal.fade.show" to target all my modals with the fade class.

Comment: Adding the same styles to .modal.fade.show works too

Comment: Thanks! I needed both, because both the `modal` panel and `body.modal-open` had the padding. But this fixed it just nicely

Answer (score 42):

A pure CSS solution that keeps the bootstrap functionality as it should be.

```css
body:not(.modal-open){
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

The problem is caused by a function in the bootstrap jQuery that adds a bit of padding-right when a modal window opens if there is a scroll bar on the page. That stops your body content from shifting around when the modal opens, and it's a nice feature. But it's causing this bug.

A lot of the other solutions given here break that feature, and make your content shift slightly about when the modal opens. This solution will preserve the feature of the bootstrap modal not shifting content around, but fix the bug.

Comment: I don't know why someone would want no CSS solution. I want no JS solution. This one looks good.

Comment: I needed this because if I Dismissed the Modal (**_after_** an Asyc-Postback inside the Modal) then it would still retain that weird padding.  However, I still needed @Benjamin Oats answer too for it to all work when I had any Scrollbars on the Page.

Comment: this one works still great with Bootstrap 4. only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 18):

If you're more concerned about the `padding-right` related thing then you can do this

**jQuery**:

```
$('#loginModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $('body').addClass('test');
});
```

this will `addClass` to your `body` and then using this

**CSS**:

```
.test[style] {
     padding-right:0 !important;
 }
```

and this will help you to get rid of `padding-right`.

But if you're also concerned about the hiding `scroll` then you've to add this too:

**CSS**:

```
.test.modal-open {
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/eLjexxzk/1)

Please have a look, it will do the trick for you.

Comment: Seems like it does not work. Or I did something wrong.
It still adds `padding-right` to `body` and increases the amount of `padding-right` by 15px each time I close the Admin Panel.

Comment: I've just checked your *link* it seems your code is not executing as its out-of `$(document).ready(function(){` try to put your *code* inside of it.

Comment: try putting an alert inside of your *code* then you can check that your *code* is not running. its working fine on fiddle and will work on your page too only if you use it accordingly

Comment: For a reason, the code does not run when the modal is shown.

Comment: One thing I do not understand is that, if the Bootstrap `modal`s add a class to `body`, it should maintain the `padding-right` to 15px, not add 15px each time the `#adminPanel` is closed

Comment: Its not just add `padding-right` but also add class as modal-open for overflow: hidden its just for hiding the **scroll-bar**,

when the modal-box open, it tries to hide the scroll bar by adding the `padding-right` and when it closes it reset the `padding-right`.

Comment: What i don't understand from normal behaviour of bootstrap you mentioned is that it does not reset the padding-right, but add 15px padding-right to body, and increase the amount of padding right each time I closed the modals.
I guess the guy below has his idea and it works.

Comment: @PhuNguyen whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Thank you so much for your effort. Have a nice day.

Comment: @PhuNguyen glad to help :)

Comment: thank you very much... this solve my case without losing the animation

Answer (score 14):

Just open bootstrap.min.css

Find this line (default)

```
.modal-open{overflow:hidden;}
```

and change it as

```
.modal-open{overflow:auto;padding-right:0 !important;}
```

It will work for every modal of the site. You can do overflow:auto; if you want to keep scrollbar as it is while opening modal dialog.

Comment: @Ashok Can you please elaborate the cause of the issue?

Comment: This solution pointed me in the right direction. But, instead of modifying bootstrap.min.css, I put .modal-open{overflow:auto;padding-right:0 !important;} in my main theme stylesheet and it worked!

Comment: Never edit bootstrap's css directly.  Always add the overrides to the css in your own stylesheet.  Just like @PratyushDeb suggested.

Comment: This isn't a great solution because it allows the content behind the modal to be scrolled.  The modal grays out that content because the user is supposed to be interacting with it and only it.

Comment: This should be most reliable answer. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I had this same problem for a VERY long time. None of the answers here worked! But the following fixed it!

```
$(document.body).on('hide.bs.modal,hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('body').css('padding-right','0');
});
```

There are two events that fire on closing of a modal, first it's `hide.bs.modal`, and then it's `hidden.bs.modal`. You should be able to use just one.

Comment: It was not working for me when I added listener for both `hide.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal`. But worked perfectly when I removed `hide.bs.modal` from the listener. :)

Comment: To the down-voter: Please leave constructive criticism in a comment so I can improve this answer.

Comment: @SamMalayek There are two issues, instead of `hide.bs.modal,hidden.bs.modal` one should use `show` and `shown` events, second `$('body').css('padding-right','0');` seems to be disregarded in the shown event somehow.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: auto !important;
}

// Bootstrap uses JS to set the element style so you can
// override those styles like this
body.modal-open[style] {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Works in Chrome!  Thanks.

Comment: I had to replace `0px` with the amount shown by an inspector for the body in rest. Works in Firefox 98 and Chromium 99. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

easy fix

add this class

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Its a override but works

Comment: This Class, combined with the answer posted by @Chasmani, made a total and complete solution for me.  Also +1 for saying "_add this class_".  It's crazy reading everyone's Responses here suggesting to override the Bootstrap.css file.  Leave that file alone, and have your own CSS File where you apply any "_Bootstrap Overrides_".  This is important so you may then document them all in one place, not lose them when updating/upgrading Bootstrap, and review them (to see if you still need the workarounds) after upgrading to a new Bootstrap Version.

Comment: I agree @MikeTeeVee that you should definitely not edit the bootstrap css. I didn't include that in my answer because I figured its slightly out of the scope for answering this question

Answer (score 3):

I'm loading the default bootstrap 3.3.0 CSS and had a similar problem.
Solved by adding this CSS:

`body.modal-open { overflow:inherit; padding-right:inherit !important;` }

The !important is because bootstrap modal javascript adds 15px of padding to the right programatically. My guess is that it's to compensate for the scrollbar, but I do not want that.

Answer (score 2):

I just removed the `fade` class and change the class fade effect with `animation.css`. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

**removeAttr won't work you will to remove the CSS property like this:**

```
        $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('body').css('padding-right','');
        });
```

With no property value, the property is removed.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but none of the answers from here removed the problem in my similar situations and I thought it would be useful for some developers to read my solution too.

I use to add some CSS to the body when a modal is opened, in the websites where it is still used bootstrap 3.

```
body.modal-open{
            padding-right: 0!important;
            overflow-y:scroll;
            position: fixed;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

With Bootstrap 4 this worked for me:

```
$(selector).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body').css('padding-right','0');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with Bootstrap 3.3.7 and my solution for fixed navbar: Adding this style to your custom css.

```
.modal-open {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

it will make your modal showed while scroll window still working.
thanks, hope this will help you too

Answer (score 1):

**My solution does not require any additional CSS.**

As pointed by @Orland, one event is still happening when the other starts. My solution is about starting the second event (showing the `adminPanel` modal) only when the first one is finished (hiding the `loginModal` modal).

You can accomplish that by attaching a listener to the `hidden.bs.modal` event of your `loginModal` modal like below:

```
$('#loginModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $('#adminPanel').modal('show');
}
```

And, when necessary, just hide the `loginModal` modal.

```
$('#loginModal').modal('hide');
```

Of couse you can implement your own logic inside the listener in order to decide to show or not the `adminPanel` modal.

You can get more info about Bootstrap Modal Events [here](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap models add that padding-right to the body if the body is overflowing.

On bootstrap 3.3.6 (the version I'm using) this is the function responsible for adding that padding-right to the body element:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L1180

A quick workaround is to simply overwrite that function after calling the bootstrap.js file:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.setScrollbar = function () { };
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
body.modal-open{
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap's existing classes to fix this by adding `pe-0` to the body tag.
That translates to

```
.pe-0 {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

So if you have access to the body tag you don't need to add any additional CSS or javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `data-target` from the button and load the modal using jQuery.

```
<button id='myBtn' data-toggle='modal'>open modal</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#myBtn").modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the bootstrap javascript and found that the Modal code sets the right padding in a function called `adjustDialog()` which is defined on the Modal prototype and exposed on jQuery. Placing the following code somewhere to override this function to do nothing did the trick for me (although I don't know what the consequence of not setting this is yet!!)

`$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.adjustDialog = function () { };`

Answer (score 0):

This can solve the problem

```
.shop-modal.modal.fade.in {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bootstrap bug and fixed in v4-dev: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/18441
till then adding below CSS class should help.

```
.fixed-padding {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem using modals and ajax. It was because the JS file was referenced twice, both in the first page and in the page called by ajax, so when modal was closed, it called the JS event twice that, by default, adds a padding-right of 17px.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    overflow-y: scroll!important;
}
```

Worked for me. Note that the Scrollbar is forced in body - but if you have a "scrolling" page anyways, it doesn't matter (?)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal,hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 setTimeout(function(){
  $('body').css('padding-right',0);
 },1000);
});
```

Try this

It will add the padding right 0px to the body after the modal close.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you open a modal that previous modal is not completely closed yet. To fix it just open new modal at the time that all modal are completely closed, check codes below:

```
  showModal() {
    let closeModal = $('#your-modal');

    closeModal.modal('hide');
    closeModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#new-open-modal').modal('show');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I now this is old, and all the solutions offered here may work. I'm just adding something new in case that could help someone: I had the same issue and noticed that opening the modal was adding a margin-right to my sidenav (probably a kind of inheritance from the padding added to the body). Adding {margin-right:0 !important;} to my sidenav did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

As @Orland says if you are using some effect like fade then there we need to wait before displaying the modal, this is a bit hacky but will do the trick.

```
function defer(fn, time) {
    return function () {
        var args = arguments,
            context = this;

        setTimeout(function () {
            fn.apply(context, args);
        }, time);
    };
}

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.show = defer($.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.show, 350);
```

Answer (score -2):

I hope there is still someone who needs this answer. There is a function called resetScrollbar() in bootstrap.js, for some stupid reason the developers decided to add the scrollbar dimensions to the body's padding right. so technically if you just set right-padding to an empty string it will fix the problem

Answer (score -2):

I have tried so many things but worked small thing for me.

```
    body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: brownFont;
    padding-right: 0 !important ;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

this should fix the issue

```
body {
    padding: 0 !important 
}
```