# Bootstrap 4 - Background move when I open a modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Has you can see here :

[https://live-example.bss.design/ (live example)](https://live-example.bss.design/)

When I open a modal (click on signup on the top menu, then on the button) the background move since the modal put the body overflow hidden.

How can I avoid that ?

Comment: It's moving because the scrollbar is being removed when the modal is opened.

Comment: Yeah, I know... That's what I mean by "modal put the body overflow hidden"

Comment: css: html { overflow-y: scroll; }

Comment: Not for html tag actually this is happened for body tag. so use this

body.modal-open {
    overflow: auto;
}

Answer (score 4):

Actually that background not moving. When Modal is open then it apply the style

```
body{overflow:hidden;}
```

So the scroll bar is disabled. So the window expanded, not only the background 
is moving.

If you don't like that please use following code,

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: If you refresh the example, that cause a double scrollbar when the modal is long : https://live-example.bss.design/

Comment: the second scroll bar comes because of your popup content. its too long

Comment: Yes... And that's a normal behavior to have a long modal when you put forms on them.

Comment: you can use "modal-lg" with "modal-dialog" so you can get big Pop-Up.

Comment: Yeah I know, but still need scrollbar

Comment: tried this. didnt work.  its the "padding-right: 6px;" added to the body.modal-open so just set it as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37780390/46270

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the background movement by using the below code

```
.modal-open, body {overflow: inherit !important;}
```

Comment: that cause a double scrollbar when the modal is long

Answer (score 0):

**"modal-open"** class is added to the *body*.

You need to change js that adds modal-open. I know it is a strange behavior, but you have to do it :)

Intercept modal click for show and remove class to body adding to another element:

i. Modal is first added to Body and then removed and added to another element

```
$('#signUpModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(body).removeClass('modal-open');
    $('#otherElement').addClass('modal-open');
});
```

ii. and then intercept also the close of the modal and add an execution of a second remove:

```
$('#signUpModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('#otherElement').removeClass('modal-open');
});
```

And you'll be fine :)

Comment: Kind of hacky, but I tried it, still moving not quite what I expect.

https://live-example.bss.design/

Comment: You're missing another thing dude! **padding-right: 17px;** is also added in style inside the body tag. Handle it as well ;)