# Page background removes when modal (with ajax called data) open

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap v4 and have a strange issue.
[image: See the gray background]

Problem comes when I open a modal with ajax called contents such as search results or any other ajax.
Immediately after opening modal, background of the page removes automatically.
[image: No background]

When I close the modal, background remains blank.
Following is the code of the modal.

```
    <div class="modal" id="paymentData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="paymentData" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-search">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="fetched-data"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This happens only when I open modals with ajax called data.

--
I noticed when I open the modal almost all the styles remove from the page. Even the styles of the navigation bar.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the background? or the entire page? does this happen ONLY when a modal spawns for an ajax call, or does it happen with EVERY modal?

Comment: @JordanRenaud No I happens only when I open the modals with ajax contents

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819725/bootstrap-header-moves-when-modal-opens/26833908
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424288/bootstrap-4-background-move-when-i-open-a-modal

Take a look at these and let me know if they're similar to your issue

Comment: @JordanRenaud - I have gone through the link. Nothing helped me :(

Comment: Provide more code so there's more context to the problem

Comment: @JordanRenaud https://pastebin.com/pMZVwFzw

Comment: can you comment out the line in the ajax call that sets the fetched-data html and see what happens?

Comment: @JordanRenaud - Then everything works fine

Comment: I had the same problem. I noticed this; After a modal was opened, when I removed it without using the .modal("hide") method, the background shadow remained. I noticed that the same situation occurs when I try to open it again while the modal is open. You should make sure that one of these situations does not occur.

Comment: @SerhatMERCAN How to close the modal without modal("hide") method?

Comment: For example $("#modalID").remove()