# Bootstrap modal adding unwanted style

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I have a page that uses a `Bootstrap` modal. When it opens I can see a style added to the **modal-open** class:

[image]

I have can correct this in the page styling itself:

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: inherit;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
}
```

but this I would rather get to the source. Any ideas as to where to find this styling? I can't find it in the `Bootstrap` css.

Comment: You are adding it not bootstrap.

Comment: Its a inline style. You can check in that html itself.

Comment: It is not in my HTML. modal-open class is added when the modal is opened.

Comment: Can you show us the modal pop-up code and by what way you opening it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7vrhLk40/ You will see in the inspector that when you click the modal button the modal-open class is added to the body. In the fiddle doesn't add the padding-right style however so I am not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past. Maybe you should see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32863121/3168185

Comment: You are right. Here is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862394/bootstrap-modals-keep-adding-padding-right-to-body-after-closed?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top